# Home Page Components in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there any way to make the Salesforce Classic custom home page components (the components that display in the sidebar on most pages in Salesforce Classic) compatible with Salesforce Lightning UI with the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme), you cannot have Home Page Components in the Lightning Experience.